# UIImage with a specific format RGB-565

Tags: ios, memory, uiimage

I'm using some images as background, and for retina display they are 640x960 pixels and saved as PNG.

Becasue they eat-up so much memory, I've saved them as RGB-565 (2 bytes per pixel, 5 pixels for red and blue, 6 pixels for green, no transparency), but the memory allocated is the same.

Is the UIImage class aware of those specific formats ?

For the memory usage, I think UIImage think is a RGBA8888 (4 bytes per pixel, 8 bits per channel).

thanks,

r.

Answer (score 0):

UIImages contain some nifty optimization strategies. One of them is probably converting an image to the native format (ARGB32 or something, I forget...) for faster rendering at run-time. At other times, it might choose to keep the image in its original PNG compressed form.

Ah see: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html says "Windows Bitmap Format (BMP) files that are formatted as RGB-565 are converted to ARGB-1555 when they are loaded.". The same will probably hold for your images.

Comment: My images are not bitmap, are PNG. In Cocos2D I see how memory goes up or down, but when using directly UIImages, the memory is always the same, there's no differene. Thanks